# Unable to post variable through http.post() in angular 4

Tags: javascript, php, angular, ionic3

I'm getting issue in angular 4 .... I am building hybrid app using ionic 3.

I have to use php as server side language for APIs, I am having issue in posting variables to http.post() request ...

variables are not passed to php file.

**Method I'm using to call API from home.ts is:**

```
var json = {var1: 'test'};

var params = 'json='+json;

let headers = new Headers();

headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

http.post("http://example.com/infoarray.php", params, headers ).subscribe (re => {
console.log(re)
})
```

I'm able to get response from API just fine but the problem is I can't pass the value of variable 'var1' to my API
on infoarray.php I'm encoding the request to json ... but didn't get variables

Comment: how you are accessing var1 in server side?

Comment: yes, I'm accessing $_POST['var1'] to php file

Comment: access it using **json** not var1. later json.var1 you can get the value of var1

Comment: Generically.  Read this: http://victorblog.com/2012/12/20/make-angularjs-http-service-behave-like-jquery-ajax/ and you can use that as a base to create something for Angular 4.  I created a similar conversion function for Angular4 / ColdFusion; which could be converted back for PHP usage--I think the array handling would need to change: https://github.com/Reboog711/AngularToColdFusionHTTPModule

Answer (score 1):

1. Check your PHP code, may be you are missing to get JSON content from Post.

   ```
   $data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
   print_r($data);
   echo $data["param"];
   ```
2. Otherwise try to add params in form data

   ```
   let headers      = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
   let options      = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers }); // Create a request option
   let url = "SERVER_URL";
   let body = 'param1='+value1+'&param2=' +value2;

   this.http.post(url, body, options)
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify()` method while processing the params:

```
var json = {var1: 'test'};

var params = 'json='+JSON.stringify(json);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `params = 'json='+json` will actually result to this: "json=[object Object]". That's because you didn't **stringify** the object first, which is done as so:

```
var params = 'json=' + JSON.stringify(json); // "json={"var1":"test"}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Use JSON.stringify() and put your headers in RequestOptions class

```
let headers = new Headers();
    headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
let requestOpt = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
    const bodyStr = JSON.stringify({var: value});

this.http
    .post(this.vocabularyPostUrl, bodyStr, requestOpt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stringify the object. Otherwise you will end in getting `"[object][object]"` rather than `"{var1: 'test'}"`.

```
JSON.stringify(json);
```